# How to localise a time period (iOS/OSX)

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, localization

Anyone know of a way to localize a time period (e.g. 2.5 days or 6 months)

It looks like the solution is to use a stringsdict file - but this strikes me as a problem that must have been solved already?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what [`NSDateComponentsFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDateComponentsFormatter_class/index.html) does. An example from the docs:

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleFull;
formatter.includesApproximationPhrase = YES;
formatter.includesTimeRemainingPhrase = YES;
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
// Use the configured formatter to generate the string.
NSString* outputString = [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:300.0];
```

gives "About 5 minutes remaining".